# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS error crash from Crashlytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics

I have to figure out why my app crashes. The problem is that on my device (iPhone 5s) it works fine, but I got a crash report from iPhone 8 Plus that doesn't make sense to me.

According to Crashlytics info, the error occurs when the user trigers a function that calls the database to retrieve some data.

```
- (NSArray*)getContent:(NSString*)ID{


    NSMutableArray *retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from contents where ID = \"%@\"",ID];

    const char* queryUTF8 = [query UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    @autoreleasepool {
        int response = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, queryUTF8, -1, &statement, nil);
        if (response == SQLITE_OK) {
```

Crashlytics reports that the error is in this line:

```
if (response == SQLITE_OK) {
```

It also mentions that this method is called from another class and specifically:

```
__43-[SessionManager calculateAllItemDistances]_block_invoke
```

SessionManager is the class, calculateAllItemDistances is the method and this is the call to the getContent method:

```
NSArray *contentData = [[self dataManager] getContent:"33"];
```

This code is inside:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

*UPDATE*
Crash report: https://pastebin.com/FsgC9fq8

Comment: Please post the full Crashlytics stack trace report and the error message. Might use pastebin.com

Comment: @battlmonstr Updated

Answer (score 5):

I bet that this crash is related to multi-threaded access to SQLite. What points that way is that you're using dispatch_get_global_queue, which maps to several threads, and also in your stack traces thread `#3` AND thread `#6` are also doing something related to DataBaseHandler/sqlite3_exec at the same time of the crash.

You shouldn't do multi-threaded SQLite unless you are really sure that you need to do it.

The easiest fix to avoid horrible things that are hard to debug and understand would be to just use a dedicated single-threaded (aka "serial") queue to access the DB instead of using dispatch_get_global_queue. See [Creating Serial Dispatch Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW6)

If you really really need multiple threads [read this](https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) and check if your code configures it right.

Comment: If that's the case then why it crashes only to some devices? Maybe because they are faster and the calls to the database happen 
 simultaneously?

Comment: Maybe. Race condition crashes are random in general. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software